# How do I get Unity working again after installing the wrong video driver?

Tags: unity, graphics

First off I did something stupid. I downloaded a Nvidia driver even though I have an integrated chipset. After installation my unity was still working. However, when I restarted my computer I got an error message saying that I can't run unity.

I uninstalled the Nvidia driver.

I restarted my computer.

Unity still does not work.

In the terminal I type "unity" and everything looks okay until I get three error messages that say this:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

followed by:

```
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXCreateContext failed
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
jesse@jesse-PC:~$ Cannot register the panel shell: there is already one running.
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Logout and, before log back in, make sure to choose **Ubuntu** instead of **Ubuntu Classic**.

Comment: Didn't work desgua. I ran it in the terminal then tried "unity" and it came up with same errors.

Comment: Can you get to a graphical environment?

Comment: I am working in ubuntu now as selected when I logged on.. same as I always have.. it just looks different. I cannot manage windows like I used to and there is no sidebar.

Comment: Run `jockey-gtk` to see if a driver can be installed to enable 3d acceleration.

Comment: If it doesn't help, you can try to logout and, before log back in, make sure to choose Ubuntu instead of Ubuntu Classic.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. It is showing Ubuntu classic even though I am in Ubuntu. There were no drivers to install by the way.

Comment: So you've lost the 3d acceleration needed to run Unity, right?

Comment: Can you paste the content of your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file?

Comment: Apparently. What is the driver that naturally comes with Ubuntu that allows unity to run?

Comment: /etc/X11/xorg.conf does not exist in /etc/X11/ on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check if you have completely removed nvidia drivers

then install intel-gpu-tools  and i965-va-driver

```
sudo apt-get install intel-gpu-tools
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
```

I hope this should work

you may need to reinstall unity and logout for change in effects

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the mesa-glx package.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Then, restart, and you should be fine.